# Xcode - Add 'Paged Tabs' within a Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development having come from a java/android background. I am trying to make a tabbed feature in a controller but I'm not after the standard TabbedController that you get at the bottom of the app.

I would like it to be similar to another popular app such as below where you see 'Menu', 'Reviews', 'Info' etc. Are there any official or good quality tutorials showing how to go about doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- Inside the Restaurants VC , add a containerView with height say 1/3 of screen from above

2- You'll get a linked empty vc , select it then embed it inside a tabBarController from Editor menu then add remaining 2 tabs (reviews and Info )